Spring integration payload casting exception
I upgraded my spring-integration-java-dsl 1.2.3 to spring-integration-core 6.3.4 after that I am facing data type issue, Whenever I try to reach the message payload, that is converting just an byte[] instead Order object and naturally, I get casting exception. I have doubt about missing a configuration parameter etc., because I could get Order object directly with old version of dependency
Here is the simplified demo project: repo
Cloud configuration in application.yml file
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        content-type: application/json
      defaultBinder: rabbit
      function:
        definition: processOrderRequestListener;                        
      bindings:                         
        processOrderRequestListener-in-0:  
          destination: orderQueue 
          group: OrderRequest 
          content-type: application/json
          consumer:
            concurrency: 10
            max-attempts: 1
        processOrderRequestListener-out-0:
          destination: processOrderRequestChannel 
          content-type: application/json

Publishing
@Bean
public Function<Message<Order>, Message<Order>> processOrderRequestListener() {
    return message -> {
        Message<Order> order = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(message.getPayload())
                .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.message.contentType", "application/json")
                .build();
        return order; 
    };
}

Consuming
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow processOrderRequestFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(PROCESS_ORDER_REQUEST_CHANNEL)
            .log(Level.TRACE, this.getClass().getName() + ".processOrderRequestFlow")
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("source", "processOrderRequestFlow"))
            .routeToRecipients(retriesRouter -> retriesRouter
                    .recipientMessageSelector(RETRIES_CHANNEL,
                            //payload is byte[] instead Order object
                            message ->  (Order)message.getPayload()
                            ...


Looks like you use Spring Cloud Stream. So, that function is bound to some destinations on the binder. Not clear how that function is connected to the flow  you are showing. Plus not clear what sends a message to that PROCESS_ORDER_REQUEST_CHANNEL . Please, clarify. This might have nothing to do with Spring Integration, but rather how Spring Cloud Stream converts those byte[] to expected object.

@ArtemBilan  thanks for your attention, I added my yml file the question. I am pointing input and output channels with stream.cloud.binding

The destination: processOrderRequestChannel means an exchange in the RabbitMQ. How is that connected with the mentioned PROCESS_ORDER_REQUEST_CHANNEL channel in your application?

Sorry for confusion, PROCESS_ORDER_REQUEST_CHANNEL  static variable for  processOrderRequestChannel. There is one more thing, if I replace routeToRecipients with route I can get Order object instead of byte[]. that is why I think that is related with Spring Integration

What I mean what sends a message to that processOrderRequestChannel where you have this IntegationFlow subscribed. Perhaps you can share with us a simple project where we can reproduce it? I don't see how changing to the route() helps. Can you share the code where it works with an Order instead of byte[]?

Okay, I will create a sample project. But for the idea, I publish message like order object  {"orderId":4353,"AccountId":5465,"CompanyId":890} to orderQueue.OrderRequest queue via rabbitmq management page. The configuration redirect to processOrderRequestChannel  as an output so processOrderRequestFlow listens that channel and consumes the message

So, Rabbit Binder just path through message.getBody() which is, essentially, byte[]. So, that is not clear how it is supposed to be converted to the Order when it comes as an input for that flow. Therefore, it would be great if you share how you configure that route() that it receives an Order as a message payload.

Hi @ArtemBilan, I  created a demo project and I added it in question. Could you have a look? Sorry for delay, thanks.

Thank you for sharing your sample!
Unfortunately Spring Boot 1.5.x is very-very old and for a long time out of support. We have to adapt our projects to whatever we can upgrade right now.
So, I see in your old project version you had this:
@StreamListener(OrderProcessor.ORDER_REQUEST_INPUT_CHANNEL)
@Output(PROCESS_ORDER_REQUEST_CHANNEL)
public Message<OrderMessage> processOrderRequestListener(final Message<OrderMessage> orderMessage) throws IOException, SQLException {
    return orderMessage;
}

Which, essentially, let Spring Cloud Stream to perform conversion on the input and then you send that message into a channel for IntegrationFlow. Not a surprise that you receive in the flow an OrderMessage instead of byte[].
I'm not sure how that  private static final String PROCESS_ORDER_REQUEST_CHANNEL = "processOrderRequestListener-out-0"; is supposed to be consumed in a new version, but I'd suggest to not use that intermediate Function at all, but rather something like:
 return IntegrationFlow.from(OrderMessageConsumer.class, gateway -> gateway.beanName("processOrderRequestListener"))

 ...
 interface OrderMessageConsumer extends Consumer<OrderMessage> {}


Thanks for your answer @Artem Bilan.  "processOrderRequestListener-out-0" is consume the message via this stream.fuction.definition in application.yml
   stream: 
      function:
        definition:
          processOrderRequestListener;
      bindings:
       processOrderRequestListener-in-0:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: orderQueue
          group: OrderRequest 
        processOrderRequestListener-out-0:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: processOrderRequestChannel


That's correct. And since that function is bound by Spring Cloud Stream, its output is converted back to byte[] in the SimpleFunctionRegistry. That's how you got just byte[] in your IntegrationFlow. That's why I suggest to not have that function at all and consume via Consumer as a gateway into an IntegrationFlow.

Aha got it! Thanks for your time and answers @Artem Bilan

Hi @Artem,     when I try to use for Supplier but can't create the exchange&queue. How can I use for Supplier?
orderDelayOutputChannel-out-0:
destination: orderDelayExchange
producer:
requiredGroups: orderDelayQueue
public interface orderDelayOutputChannel extends Supplier<Message> {}
in a integrationflow:
.<OrderMessage>handle((orderMessage, headers) -> {
    ...
    return orderMessage;
}).channel("orderDelayOutputChannel-out-0").get();


The code is not readable in the comments. Please, consider to raise a new SO thread with more info.

Hi @Artem, thanks for your comment
I raised a new question here
